# WordPress fluent form - radio button text CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I have a contact form I've created using fluent forms in WordPress.

In WordPress - fluent forms - on the selected form.  I've gone to "Setting and Integrations"  and I'm trying to add custom CSS.  The form in CSS speak is "fluent_form_3"

All my other css is working, see [www.brujitacasa.com/testQJS](http://www.brujitacasa.com/testQJS) for example, but I can not get the radio buttons to change their colour to white so they can be seen.

I've tried setting

- .fluentform .ff-el-form-check label.ff-el-form-check-label
- ff-el-form-check-input
- ff-el-form-check-radio
- ff-el-form-check
- ff-el-form-check-
- ff_item_selected

Some examples I've tried are.... It seems so simple, but I'm missing something.

```css
    form.fluent_form_3 .ff-el-form-control {     color: white; /*#495057; / *change font color*/
    }

    /*Change label styles*/
    .ff-el-input--label{
    font-size:22px; /*change label font size*/
        color: white; /*change label color*/
    }


    /* all the input fields + dropdown options */
    form.fluent_form_3 label { color: white; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to adjust the styling of native elements. That won't work; styling radio-buttons (& checkboxes) requires you to hide the input and recreate it. This is usually done by styling the pseudo elements (before & after) of the label.

Examples (incl. code): https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/styling-radio-buttons/

Comment: That explains why nothing I did worked.  But why are these different than a button or a label?

Comment: Standardization politics I guess:) Just build yourself some scaffolding and reap the rewards in every future project.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer is VERY simple. because the label is not in the input all you need is

`form.fluent_form_3 .ff-el-form-check-label span { color: white;}`

where fluent_form_3 is the code for your specific form